# ctype - python - long int too long to convert -

Tags: python, ctypes

problem:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Nutzer\Google
>   Drive\Code\Code\memory_read.py", line 26, in 
>       byref(bytesRead)) ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: : **long int too long to convert**

code:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

PID = 4016

address = 0x6C532407C

OpenProcess = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess
ReadProcessMemory = windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
CloseHandle = windll.kernel32.CloseHandle


PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF

datadummy = b'.'*200
buffer = c_char_p(datadummy)
bufferSize = len(buffer.value)
bytesRead = c_ulong(0)

processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, int(PID))

ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, 
    address, 
    buffer, 
    bufferSize, 
    byref(bytesRead))

CloseHandle(processHandle)
```

I tried to change the bytesRead = c_ulong(0) to some other ctypes, but no success. Im on a Windows 8.1 System 64bit. I couldnt find any solution or similiar problems after hours of searching. Does someone know whats wrong here?

Comment: Set `SIZE_T = c_size_t;` `ReadProcessMemory.argtypes = [HANDLE, LPCVOID, LPVOID, SIZE_T, POINTER(SIZE_T)];` `OpenProcess.restype = HANDLE;` `CloseHandle.argtypes = [HANDLE]`.

Comment: Don't modify Python strings. Create an array using `create_string_buffer` or just using normal ctypes syntax, e.g. `bufferSize = 201;` `buffer = (c_char * bufferSize)()`.

Comment: Make sure to use the right type for the out parameter, `bytesRead = SIZE_T()`. That's 8 bytes in Win64.

Comment: BTW, argument 2 is `address`. The default argument type is a 32-bit `int`, for which the given value is out of range. The `argtypes` that I suggested instead uses `LPCVOID` for this parameter, i.e. a `void *` pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of fail and error I finally have an answer.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
import ctypes

OpenProcess = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess
ReadProcessMemory = windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
CloseHandle = windll.kernel32.CloseHandle

PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF

pid = 2320
address = 0x00C98FCC

buffer = c_char_p(b"The data goes here")
val = c_int()
bufferSize = len(buffer.value)
bytesRead = c_ulong(0)

processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)

if ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, bufferSize, byref(bytesRead)):
    memmove(ctypes.byref(val), buffer, ctypes.sizeof(val))

    print("Success: " + str(val.value))
else:
    print("Failed.")

CloseHandle(processHandle)
```